# How to combine / append PDFs according to name of file?

Tags: python, list, loops, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a bunch of files that all start with department name. I want to have one file for each department, so instead of 4 anesthesia files and  4 dermatology files, I have 1 big files of anesthesia and 1 big file of dermatology.

Right now the code below will know how to make two files. But not know when to properly stop appending one department and start a new department. I get two files right now. One that has all of Anesthesia (and looks good) and stops. And one file of Dermatology, but it contains both the anesthesia files and derm files.

Is there a way to restart the append start point in my loops. I apologize, I'm not very good at lists/loops here:

```
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger


department_list =['Anesthesiology','Dermatology']
file_dict = {}
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/username/Documents/Tests"):
    for file in files:
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
        for dept in department_list:
            if filepath.__contains__(dept):
                file_dict[file] = filepath
                merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
                for k, v in file_dict.items():
                    print(k, v)
                    merger.append(v)
                    merger.write(dept + ' combined_result.pdf')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going through files and check, if they belong in the department.

However, you are creating a single file_dict which keeps *all* files belonging to *different* departments instead of only files for a single department.

You need to move merging out of the loop which assigns files to departments. A more elegant solution would match files already by department initally via glob.glob() and avoid double looping, but that would also mean some rewrite.

The simplest way to change your existing code (but it could be improved):

```
file_dict={ dept:{} for dept in department_list } # seed file_dict with departments
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/username/Documents/Tests"):
    for file in files:
        filepath = os.path.join(subdir,file) # note changed check
        for dept in department_list: 
            if dept in filepath: #note changed from __contains__. Usually you needn't call __ funcs in your code
                file_dict[dept][file] = filepath

for dept in department_list:
    merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False)
    for k, v in file_dict[dept].items():
       print(k, v)
       merger.append(v)
    merger.write(dept + ' combined_result.pdf')
```

Comment: Almost works! yours splits it...but it adding/appending everything from the beginning every time it hits a match. So say there's 4 Dermatology reports. The combined report takes report (1) then adds report (1)(2), then (1)(2)(3), then reports (1)(2)(3)(4) <-- (just this last iteration is what i'd want) . So I end up with 10 in the bundle...not just 4. Any thoughts? Once again, thanks for looking into this to even begin with.

Comment: @pjhollow please edit your post to include some example of actual file names with directories. You can obscure any confidential information, but I would like to see examples of directories and filenames that contain department

Comment: got it to work. merger.write at the end just had an extra tab in it.